# how to handle with nested objects from js in dart (new dart-js-interop)

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I created add-in for Outlook Office365 and i used their `office.js` to be able to get an information from email.

dart.js example:

```
js.context['Office']['context']['mailbox']['userProfile']['emailAddress']
```

or

```
js.context['Office']['context']['mailbox']['item']['to'].callMethod('getAsync', [callback(result)])
```

How can i use new [dart-js-interop](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/js/0.6.0/) for such needs?

Answer (score 1):

```
@JS('Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress')
external get emailAddress;
```

```
@JS('Office.context.mailbox.item.to.getAsync')
external getAsync(Function callback);
```

when you call `getAsync` you need to wrap the function you pass to callback with `allowInterop` or `allowInteropCaptureThis`

```
getAsync(allowInterop((x) => print(x)));
```

Try with caution. I played a bit with the new dart-js-interop a few months ago but didn't use it myself in real code yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps me for static calls. Yep it's actually `mailbox` :)

Comment: By the way, how to deal with `JSObjectImpl`? it has no methods such as `callMethod()` or `['fieldName']`.

Comment: Not sure, I guess you need to cast it to a concrete type. Where do you get it from?

Comment: I tryed to cast, but it's always the instance of `JSObjectImpl`. It goes from `js_dartium.dart`:
'    class JSObjectImpl extends JSObject $implementsClause {
      JSObjectImpl.internal() : super.internal();
    }'

Comment: I meant - where do you get the reference from. What function/getter, ... does return it?

Comment: `@JS('Office.context.mailbox.item.to')
external get to;`

and the running code:

`main {
  print(to[0]);
}`

`to` getter returns JSArrayImpl

Comment: I think you need to create a mapping class and use it to type the callback using a typedef. I can have another look tomorrow. Time for bed.

Comment: JSArrayImpl implements List, so you can index it that way. and it won't have field names, it's an array. For JSObjectImpl that indicates something you haven't wrapped, and you need to wrap it, or it does have a subscript operator which you should be able to use.